# ¿Hay alguna manera de convertir una palabra mayúscula en minúscula sin el metodo ToLower()?

Tags: c#

Quisiera intentar alguna forma de convertir una palabra mayúscula en una minúscula sin necesidad del metodo .ToLower. Esto es más por mera curiosidad, sé que es más practico y rapido usar ese metodo. Así es como está mi codigo. Muchas gracias

```
        string palabra; 

        Console.WriteLine("Digite una palabra en mayúscula");
         palabra = Console.ReadLine(); 
        
       for (int i = 0; i < palabra.Length; i++) 
        {
           if (palabra[i] >= 'A' && palabra[i] <= 'Z')
                Console.Write(Char.ToLower(palabra[i]));
        }
       Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Hay varias maneras, podrías tener una lista donde tengas todas las mayúsculas seguido de todas las minúsculas, hacer una búsqueda y reemplazo. Tu pregunta queda basada en opiniones, que no te sorprenda si resulta cerrada. Aquí unas recomendaciones: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Hay un hecho curioso sobre la codificación ASCII y que también aplica a codificaciones basadas en él.

Si miras la tabla hay una diferencia de 32 entre la letra **A** y la **a**. Es probable que haya sido hecho a propósito.

Entonces, vista la diferencia, puedes sumarle 32 para convertirlo en minúscula o restarle para mayúscula:

```
char c = (char)('A' + 32) // 'a'
```

El único detalle es que la **Ñ** se encuentra aparte. Así que no creo que funcione con ella.

Answer (score 0):

**Convertir letra o palabra en mayúsculas a minúsculas sin usar .ToLower()**

Un método puede ser obtener los caracteres y en caso de ser mayúscula convertirlos a minúscula, sumando al valor del caracter la diferencia de 'a' - 'A' (32), ejemplo:

```
String cadena = "HakiRU en StackOverflow";
char[] charArray = cadena.toCharArray();
int dif = 'a' - 'A';

for (int i=0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
    if (charArray[i] >= 'A' && charArray[i] <= 'Z') {
        charArray[i] += dif;
    }
}

System.out.println(charArray);
```

la salida a partir de la cadena inicial `"HakiRU en StackOverflow"` sería:

```
  hakiru en stackoverflow
```